# how to list out only specific files in S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto, bucket

I have n-number of files in a s3-bucket, where I want to download only specific pattern type of files w.r.t their naming conventions

**Code:**

```
BUCKET_NAME = "MYBucket"
s3_conn  = boto.connect_s3(AWS_keys)
bucket = s3_conn.get_bucket(BUCKET_NAME)

#goto through the list of files
bucket_list = bucket.list(prefix='Test_folder/OUT/abc_')

for l in bucket_list:
    key_string = str(l.key)
    s3_path = DOWNLOAD_LOCATION_PATH + key_string
    try:
       print ("Current File is ", s3_path)
       l.get_contents_to_filename(s3_path)
    except (OSError,S3ResponseError) as e:
         pass
```

Above code works fine for only one type of File Naming ie: **abc**_

What if I want list of files with pattern like: **abc_, axy_, xa_ya_zf_, gelnique_**

Any Suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

A delimiter can be specified together with prefix. AWS S3 builds a common prefix from these two and returns content in the bucket matching the common prefix.

```
bucket_list = bucket.list(prefix='Test_folder/OUT/', delimiter='_')
```

Common prefixes is a substring from the beginning of the key to the first occurrence of the specified delimiter after the prefix. This doesn't guarantee only matches like `'Test_folder/OUT/abc_'` but also `'Test_folder/OUT/mydir/abc_'`.

Comment: This doesn't match with my need. What I thought of a regex like python to handle within this bucket.list()

Comment: AFAIK, the API doesn't support using regexes for prefixes and that's is reasonable since keys can contain any character. When you say it doesn't match with your need, do you have other paths in `Test_folder/OUT/`? You may want to reorganize the contents of `Test_folder/OUT/` so that you can list them using a common prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Instead this Simple looping worked fine for me

```
pattern_list = ['abc_', 'axy_', 'xa_ya_zf_', 'gelnique_']
for p in pattern_list:
    prefix ='AB_Test/OUT/' + str(p)
    for k in src_bucket.list(prefix): 
          # Do your work!
```